# "Permission denied" with Internet Explorer and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I try to do an AJAX call with jQuery and `$.post` in Internet Explorer, but all I get is an error saying "Permission denied". The problem is kinda weird since it occurs only when I access a page after I was on any other page.

For instance I type the URL in the adress line and let IE load the page. Then I click on a button so the script should start loading JSON data. (The script providing the data lies on the same server and I access it with a relative URL, so using a different domain is not the problem here. Even tried to use a absolute URL with the same host part.)

But when I refresh the page then and try it again it works! Same thing when I come to that page from another page. At first nothing works, but when I click "refresh" everything is fine.

IE gives me the error message "Permission denied" while in every other browser I don't notice this behaviour. Since I have tried many things and still cannot imagine where the problem lies I'd like to ask you what you think the problem might be?

**edit:**
A small example:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de"> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ietest/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ietest/test.js"></script> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**ajax.html**

```
It works!
```

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'a' ).click(function(){
        $.post( '/ietest/ajax.html', function( data ) {
            alert( data );
        });
    });
});
```

Try it here: http://t1318.greatnet.de/ietest/test.html

Comment: Can you post your code? That would help :)

Comment: There it is ;) I've read about that problem several times when I've been searching for a solution. Sadly no one had a clue what's going on.

Comment: Which versions of IE are you getting this in?

Comment: IE 7 and also 8 (someone else tested it for me)

Comment: I added a link where you can try it yourself.

Comment: something very similar is happening to me now with ie 11. with jQuery 1.6.4. would love some help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the post on jquerys forum [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/obscure-ie-bug-in-jquery-1-4), you have to have the content type meta as the first item in your head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ietest/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ietest/test.js"></script>  
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its local (localhost), then for security reasons you have to have the full path.

Comment: Tried it here with `http://192.168.0.5/ietest/ajax.html`. Other browsers do it, IE still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the jquery version worked. Instead of using version 1.9.1, now I'm using 1.12.4 and it works.