# Jquery Min ACCESS DENIED on Internet Explorer 8 & 7 Problem?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Hello there i have tried all solutions to fix this problem on stack overflow the problem doesn't seem to go away.

Below is the code i am using for an ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"http://website.appspot.com/Setup?action=addRules",
             data:  "params=" + objStr

         });
```

Every time i use this i get the error. it use to work before. I tried using jQuery 1.4.2 & 1.4.1, this form works on all other browsers. Thanks for your help.

Edit:

here is data for objStr

```
    ruleObj[i] = {
                "user":"name",
                "eventName":"CheckIn",
                "location":locationArray[i],
                "startDate":startDateArray[i],
                "endDate":endDateArray[i],
                "startTime":startTimeArray[i],
                "endTime": endTimeArray[i],
                "eventType":2,
                "days": dayTotal,
                "Actions":"32",
                "trueAction":"32",
                "falseAction":"32",

        };
    }

var objStr = JSON.stringify(ruleObj[i]);
```

My Header HTML:

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.web.com/MVP/site/dist/jquery.jqplot.css" />
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.web.com/MVP/site/dist/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the contents of objStr?

Comment: That code works here. What exactly is `objStr`?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960153/permission-denied-with-internet-explorer-and-jquery

Comment: noone can help you without more information, please include a sample of your html include **everything** in your `<head>` tags

Comment: xzyfer i tried that post but did not fix the problem thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making the request to a different server than the one the request is coming from? If yes, then you need [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

Also, make sure that objStr is properly url encoded.

Answer (score 1):

your augument is wrong. try this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://website.appspot.com/Setup",
    data: {action: "addRules", params: objStr}
 });
```

i'm not sure u can do ajax cross domain. try $.load instead

```
$.load({
  url: "http://website.appspot.com/Setup",
  data: {action: "addRules", params: objStr},
  success: function(data, stts, xhr){
    // do something
  }  
});
```

but destination has to accept verb GET

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does not fix the access denied problem.

Comment: is it ajax cross site? becus url its different domain. i update code too. hope it fix

Answer (score 0):

Look here for the answer: ["Permission denied" with Internet Explorer and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960153/permission-denied-with-internet-explorer-and-jquery)