# Updating jQuery and jQuery UI files gives error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I just updated an local version of jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.6.4.

When I try to access the widget `button` or  `dialog` IE throws me a "permission denied" error in jQuery. I Follow the trace and found that the error was in the function `evalScript` in the jQuery file.

Here is how I called the button and dialog :

```
$('.button').button();
$('.button').css('margin-top', '10px');
$('#dialogAlerte').dialog({
                             'title':opinionLabel['_L_AVERTISSEMENT'][langue],
                             'autoOpen':false,
                             'modal':true,
                             'draggable':false,
                             'resizable':false
                          });
```

I found the following question, but it does not fit this context : ["Permission denied" with Internet Explorer and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960153/permission-denied-with-internet-explorer-and-jquery)

EDIT :

- It was working with jQuery 1.4.2.
- There is `Tabs` before in the code and the tabs are display correctly

Comment: The most helpful thing you can do is to include the minimal amount of code it takes to reproduce the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net, to make it easier for us to see the environment causing the problem to occur.

Comment: shouldn't this be asked to jqueryui support? i mean we can't debug jquery ui for you :) so i agree with @Matt

Comment: @DanyKhalife Thanks where Do I do that ?

Comment: @DavidLaberge
there you go : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/
wow i just noticed you're the 2nd canadian guy ive met on this site cool :D

Comment: @DanyKhalife could you post your comment in the answer so you could earn the point you deserve.  Thanks fellow Canadian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we figure out the issue. So for the next guy out there who runs into this issue here the solution.

The HTML look something like that:

```
<div id="dialogRecherche">
    <label><script>document.write('Hello World')</script></label>
</div>
```

The call to a jQuery-ui that has a `script` tag into it gives the error.

Comment: hmm i am wondering if its because you have a missing ; inside that script tag

Answer (score 1):

You can post a bug report on jquery ui : bugs.jqueryui.com

Im sure they will fix it in no time ;)