# jquery load function not working in IE and shows Object required error

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the jquery load function to load a page. It is working fine in FF but in IE it shows the error message as the following

```
 Message: Object required
    Line: 24
    Char: 1
    Code: 0
    URI: http://sample/index.php?option=com_propertylist&amp;controller=propertylist&amp;view=propertylist&amp;propty=220


    Message: Permission denied
    Line: 6081
    Char: 6
    Code: 0
    URI: http://sample/templates/sample/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
```

The code is

```
 jQuery("#listing a").bind('click', function(){
            jQuery(".dashboard-listing").empty();
            overlayapply();
            jQuery(".dashboard-listing").load('index.php?option=com_propertylist&controller=listing&task=overview&propty='+propertyid+'&tmpl=component',null,function(){overlayremove();}); 
        });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do we have to guess the code you used?

Comment: similar thread ( permission denied ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960153/permission-denied-with-internet-explorer-and-jquery see if it helps