# IE permission denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, permission-denied

I am getting permission denied error on IE (firefox it works fine)

I am making an ajax call (local domain) and result of the call I am assigning to a div. On debugging I came to know there is no issue with ajax call and variable 'result' has the result data. Error is thrown when data is being assigned to div.

**Error** Line: 2 jquery-1.8.1.min.js Error: Permission denied

**Javascript code:**

```
$.get('administration.htm', function (result) {
    $('#adminDiv').find('#content').html(result);
});
```

Any idea why this error is coming.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2960963/953684

Comment: I already have meta tag defined in head tag.

Comment: is the target div in an iframe?

Comment: instead of using $('#adminDiv').find('#content').html(result) I tried to change it to document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=result;

Now i am not getting this error but events defined on result does not work and even formatting is not correct.

Comment: no, target div is not in an iframe

Comment: does your html have a file input?

Comment: Do you have base tag in head tag of page?

Comment: No... pasting head tag below

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Agent hub - Admin edition</title>

        <!-- css files -->
        //..............
  //..............

        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui.min-1.8.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(function() {
                // ......javascript code
            });

       </script>
    </head>

Comment: instead of using $('#adminDiv').find('#content').html(result) I tried to change it to document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=result; 

Error is gone but formatting and events are not working. I guess following is the reason

Since my result has css, js resources which gets downloaded in ajax request are not being downloaded  [if i use jquery's html method it generally downloads them, but not sure about innerHtml] hence formatting and events are not working. Any idea how to download css, js files while setting innerHtml to result?

Comment: `.getScript()` for js

Answer (score 2):

The permission denied error could be coming from trying to manipulate the DOM before the document is ready.

As for the events and formatting no longer working, using JavaScript and jquery to select things can cause issues. When you use `document.getElementById` it will update the DOM and the rendered page but it will not update the associated jQuery objects. To solve this you either need to re-generate the jQuery object (using `$('selector')`) and reattach the handlers or try something like `$(document.getElementById('objectId')).html('result');` where you use javascript to find the DOM element to avoid the permission error then modify it using the associated jQuery object.

Comment: I doubt attempting to acces elements before they have been loaded produces `Error: Permission denied`. And `document.getElementById` does not update the DOM. What do you think it changes?

Comment: Hi @Oriol. Trying to access dom elements before they are loaded definitely will cause this error in some browsers. In my answer I was referring to manipulating the DOM using the objects returned by `document.getElementById` and `$('selector')` not the functions themselves.