# Jquery ajax: on click function not working in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I have three tabs with a lot of different categories on each. Clicking each gets results from database. I am using jquery and ajax functions an php to display results. it is working perfectly but it breaks in IE, now currently it does not work in IE. If I refresh IE, it shows results otherwise nothing.

Here is a code for when one of the categories is clicked in a tab.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    window.onload = my_code();

    $(".my_link_3").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        search_ajax_way_3(this.id);
    });
});

function search_ajax_way_3(blockId) {
    $("#search_results_3").show();

    var search_this = $("#search_query").val();
    $.post("../../../php/search_1.php", {
        searchit: search_this,
        'blockId': blockId
    }, function (data) {
        $("#display_results_3").html(data);
    })
}

function search_ajax_way_base(blockId) {
    $("#search_results_1").show();

    var search_this = $("#search_query").val();
    $.post("../../../php/search_1.php", {
        searchit: search_this,
        'blockId': blockId
    }, function (data) {
        $("#display_results_1").html(data);
    })
}

function my_code() {
    search_ajax_way_base("rad1");
}
```

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` should not exist in the `$(document).ready(function(){`. What if you want to call an ajax function *before* the DOM is ready?

Comment: *How* does it break in IE?  Don't just dump the code here and say "it's not working, fix it."  Describe the problem.  What indication do you have that it doesn't work as expected?  Is there an error?  When you debug this, at what point does it fail?

Comment: @David: I just posted a portion a of my code, not the entire thing. So definitely I am not hoping for someone to do the entire thing for me. I am only asking for pointers. There is no error in FF, I used Firebug but nothing, in IE when the tab is clicked it shows no results as if the click does not fire the event at all. But after refreshing it starts working. Debugger shows no errors either. Works just fine in any other browser. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a long shot... Try using root-relative instead of relative urls.  I seem to remember once experiencing a similar problem in different browsers, when relative urls are used for .post().

Comment: @stefan: Just tried your method: didn't work! Any other ideas?

Comment: Tried absolute url...?

Comment: It seems you also have to make sure your `meta content-type` tag is above all other tags: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2960153/888177

Comment: I am going insane! So I have absolute url now, also meta content-type is topmost in header. Still have no clue what's wrong!

Comment: And it does work perfectly fine, after I refresh the page once....Does that mean something?

Comment: Grasping at straws here... try using a different version of jQuery.  And, slowly build and test your code (line by line) in IE until you see exactly when the error occurs.