# IE 11 Permission Denied Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have created a trivial HTML/JS/Angular page (below) which when first rendered in IE 11, throws a Permission Denied exception. See images of the debugger console below. My IE version is 11.0.9 on Windows 7.

[EDIT] See source below. Meta tag included, but this does not resolve the issue. txs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ie11bug">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>IE 11 Bug</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    </head>

   <body>
       <div ng-controller="AppController">
           Hello {{pageTitle}}
       </div>
       <script>
           var app = angular.module('ie11bug', []).controller('AppController', function($scope) {
               $scope.pageTitle = "This will not appear when page is 1first loaded";
           });
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried various versions of Angular from 1.4 to 1.6, same result. After clearing the cache and loading the page the error occurs. If I then reload, the page successfully renders.

The error always seems to be thrown when the factory method (called from the $exceptionHandler) assigns the $log service into the cache.

I also get Permission denied when simply trying to log to the console

```
<script>
  console.log("hello");
</script>
```

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Permission denied" with Internet Explorer and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960153/permission-denied-with-internet-explorer-and-jquery)

Comment: You haven't shown your complete code, so I can't say for sure if this is a dupe. Look over the link.

Comment: Hi thanks but the meta tag does not resolve this issue. thanks

Comment: Did you read all the answers? There a couple other solutions as well.

Comment: Hi the other answers are not relevant. I am not using jquery and the error occurs whether I server the page from localhost, file system or a seperate internal linux server. thanks

Comment: Ran your code on IE11, no issues. [This article talking about the error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191336/-permission-denied-script-error-in-internet-explorer-11) suggests installing a security update.

Comment: Hi, yes I saw some articles about that. You will see from the image that I included that the Update version I have is KB4025252 from July 2017, which is the latest cumulative security update.